# MySQL max functions on sum function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using sakila DB in mySQL. I need to present the name of the client with the highest amount of payments paid in 2005 (it's for homework, I hope it's OK to ask). I solved the problem with this query:

```
SELECT first name, last name, SUM(amount) AS total
FROM sakila.payment JOIN sakila.customer USING(customer_id)
WHERE YEAR(payment_date)=2005
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I'm sure there is a much more elegant way to solve this. I don't understand why this query didn't work:

```
SELECT first name, last name, MAX(total)
FROM     
(SELECT first name, last name, SUM(amount) AS total
FROM sakila.payment JOIN sakila.customer USING(customer_id)
WHERE YEAR(payment_date)=2005
GROUP BY customer_id) amounts;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, why is the second query wrong?

Comment: When you say it didnt work, what didnt work about it?

Comment: Stick with the first query (after you fix its syntax errors). It is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second just gets you the MAX(total) and a random first_name & random last_name since the group by is in the inner query (P.S. Either quote your "first name" as an alias or get the correct field name in place, else your queries will not really run).

Also your query needs a small correction (I just notice):

```
SELECT first_name,last_name, total 
FROM (
SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) AS total
FROM sakila.payment JOIN sakila.customer USING(customer_id)
WHERE YEAR(payment_date)=2005
GROUP BY customer_id ) total_alias
INNER JOIN sakila.customer scu ON total_alias.customer_id=scu.customer_id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

YOu were returning first name and last name with a group by: 
Results in a group by either have a function applied to them (SUM, MIN, MAX, etc) or are in the group by statement. If that is not the case, the query fails or returns random data (depends on query structure and DBMS)